# i use bcrypt to hash password but when i use postman to test api it gives me this error :>>>

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, mern, bcrypt

i use bcrypt to hash password but when i use postman to test api it gives me this error :>>> data must be a string or Buffer and salt must either be a salt string or a number of rounds

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import { userModel } from "../../database/models/user.model.js"


export const checkEmail = async(req,res,next) => {
     
    let user = await userModel.findOne({ email : req.body.email})
    if (user) return res.json({message:"email already exists."})

  
   req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync( req.body.password , 8)

    next()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- make sure password type is string

  if password type is undefined bcrypt will throw this error
- use bcrypt.genSalt method instead

move this code

```js
req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password , 8)
```

to

```js
req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, await bcrypt.genSalt())
```